# CSS fade not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I wrote this function in javascript:

```
function unhide(el, dur = 300, display = "block") {
    el.style.display = display;
    el.style.transitionDuration = dur + "ms";
    el.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

For some reason, this isn't working in Chrome.

I remember having a problem like this, due to the browser not applying Javascript-written CSS atomically.

So, I tried putting a break point after the display was changed:

```
function unhide(el, dur = 300, display = "block") {
    el.style.display = display;
●   el.style.transitionDuration = dur + "ms";
    el.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

This fixed the problem.

This same issue occurs in FireFox, but not Microsoft edge.

How can I fix this?

Is there a way to force the browser to apply the display, and then the opacity?

---

I just thought about using a `setTimeout` (*for setting the opacity, because, again, the display is not atomically applied*), however, that seems like a messy/inefficient hack.

Comment: Apart from being messy, does setTimeout solve it?

Comment: I'll check now.

Comment: @tobiq Use query fadein and fadeout functions look out for these example https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadeout  
 and  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein

Comment: @Rohit I'm not willing to import the jQuery library to fix this minute issue.

Comment: @FreemanLambda It works temperamentally. The longer the time out, the more likely it works, though. 30+ms == works.

Comment: *Guessing* -- you can't transition the display property. Perhaps it is *that* aspect the transition is choking on.

Comment: @Tobiq I made a minimal implementation with SO snippets and it seems to be working even with 0 timeouts. I will post it as an answer so that I dont create a jsfiddle for that.

Comment: @Metis I'm not trying to transition it...

Comment: @Metis The `transition-property` is set to `opacity`. What do you mean??

Comment: if i can apply an atomic set of styles and then have just one browser reflow, then i would'n say there is a problem, just my two cents. Timeout(0) is the way to go.

Comment: yes, it is 0. (That's how I can see that the element is appearing, just with no fade).

Comment: Well, you can't transition display at all. So my thought was including display in the function was perhaps where the inconsistency was coming from. And it would explain why a longer transition worked (because it would wait for display to toggle). I realize you aren't *directly* trying to transition display... but it is part of the function. Seems Freeman may have a solution below though.

Comment: Freemans answers is a direct copy of the solution I proposed (the proof of concept). What does the display being in the function have to do with the lack of a fade? It's not being transitioned (The hide method sets the display to none after an interval).

Comment: Freeman's answer sets a timeout.. waiting for display to toggle **then** it transitions the opacity. It doesn't try and transition both properties. Trying to transition the display property as part of a function will *often* result in transition issues.

Comment: @Metis Did you read what I said? That's the exact same code I proposed, and used. I didn't apply the timeout to the whole function, only the opacity setting...

Comment: Okay... I don't see that posted anywhere but in Freeman's answer. So maybe I missed it. It's certainly not in the question.

Comment: It's pretty clear what I meant, which is why Freeman understood what I was going for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As theorised, its been noted that the browser groups JS-applied CSS alterations together.

---

> Is there a way to force the browser to apply the display, and then the opacity?`

Yes. Add the line:

```
el.offsetWidth;
```

between the two CSS alterations.

This forces the browser to re-render the pages CSS.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("hidden");
unhide(el);

function unhide(el, dur = 300, display = "block") {
    el.style.display = display;
    el.style.transitionDuration = dur + "ms";
    el.offsetWidth;
    el.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden" style="display: none; opacity: 0;">Unhidden</div>
```

Comment: Didn't know this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Minimal implementation with a requestAnimationFrame

```js
function unhide(el, dur = 1000, display = "block") {
    console.log("opacity when display none: ", getComputedStyle(mrHyde, null).opacity);
    el.style.display = display;
    console.log("opacity when display block: ", getComputedStyle(mrHyde, null).opacity)
    el.style.transitionDuration = dur + "ms";
    requestAnimationFrame(() => el.style.opacity = 1);
}

const mrHyde = document.getElementById("unhideMe");
unhide(mrHyde);
```

```css
#unhideMe {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="unhideMe">Mr. Hyde</div>
```

**EDIT**
I replaced `setTimeout` with `requestAnimationFrame`. The end result is the same but I feel `requestAnimationFrame` is more suited for this purpose.

**EDIT 2**
This behavior is actually already reported as a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121340). The very last comment on the thread raises a hypothesis that I also was speculating on. Perhaps the browser "discards" the numeric value of `opacity` when the element is in `display: none`. That would imply that setting the `opacity: 1` does not trigger a css transition, because transitions only work on well defined style property values.
On the very next event loop, the browser will have a defined `opacity` value for the element, because it is by now in `display: block`.

I took a small step into proving this hypothesis by logging the computed style value of the element when it is in `display: none` and right after it switches to `display: block`. Both values are actually a well defined numeric `0`, so this goes against the hypothesis.

**PS:** http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe
Coverage for `requestAnimationFrame` seems to be fairly acceptable as of 2017, including IE > 9 versions.

Comment: It's working here on SO. I'll try it again in my code

Comment: Yeah, the stripped-down version seems to be working. Maybe you have some impediment in your current environment (css or js)

Comment: I believe, instead of the - already in the question proposed - workaround, this question is worth an explanation of why this happens, thus the 3 upvotes.

Comment: @deblocker you are right, this is not meant as an "accepted answer". This  answer is meant as a minimal working solution here on SO, without residing to jsfiddle or other external sandobxes.

Comment: @FreemanLambda: no worries, your answer is about "how to solve that", that's, at the end, the most useful thing...

Comment: Freeman, requestAnimationFrame actually worked, however, I'm worried about support... Actually, who cares about ie10<